# how would i have cickable images in the corner of my page

Tags: html, css

the only time the clickable images worked was when their positions reset and they only were in position when they weren't clickable

here's when the positions reset but were clickable https://x6vsn.netlify.app/watermark00 here's the one where it's in place but it not clickable https://x6vsn.netlify.app/watermark0point1

Comment: Please show your work, add your code

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the first and position your images with `position: absolute`.

For example, on an image to put it in the bottom right corner:

```html
...
<img class="bottom-right" src="..." /
...
```

```css
img.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

And it you want it to be relative to its direct container, you can set `position: relative` to the container it has be relative to.

edit: I see that you're problem is with the `z-index: -99` on the second link. If you remove it, it works just fine.